# How can I enter a finite amount of numbers when called from a text file in a variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to call a text file as follows:

```
with open (r'C:\1\number.txt') as codes_1:
    newcodes = [line.rstrip ("\n") for line in codes_1]
```

A `code` variable is defined (in the site web) by a maximum 10 number of numbers that you can enter and no more is allowed to be added.

```
code = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "code")))
code.send_keys("".join(newcodes)[0:9])
```

The text file contains the following (is a fragment of txt):

```
File.txt:
123434132
940328334
```

I prevent the following line from being added to the previous one:

```
1234341329
```

The problem is that when trying to add to the `newcodes` variable and insert line by line according to the length of lines that the text file has, it crashes because when the "940328334" is added to the previous one, the page does not recognize the new code that was formed and crashes..

It occurred to me to try to define a new variable called

```
limit = ("".join(newcodes)[:9])
```

where 9 is the maximum number of numbers that can be entered and no more are allowed.

But with the example I gave you, it doesn't work for me. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes" and "it doesn't work"?

Comment: When the following line is added to the previous one, the page does not recognize the new code that was formed and crashes.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. Please show a *complete* example: show enough code that someone else can copy and paste it and run it to see the problem; show exactly what happens when you try that code; and explain exactly what is supposed to happen instead.

Comment: Addition to Karl, also please try to provide expected output. You want first 9 Characters or 10 Characters I am confused.

Comment: First 9, but it is defined by a limit of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to do this :

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    print([x.rstrip("\n")[:9] for x in f.readlines()])
```

`.readlines()` will read each line and make a list of that and we are iterating through that list and selecting only first 9 characters from that..

Comment: Yep, it works! It's exactly what I was trying to do. Sorry for not explaining very well, my English is not very good. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad it helped. :)